# Authentication Signout and back button asp .net

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem in my asp.net pages

We are using form authentication. Once page is signed out I am able to go back to the previous page. This is due to pages cached in browser.

So i disabled the cache. But this has its own drawbacks.

- If user is logged in he will not be able to navigate to the previous page using back button since no cache available in the browser.
- if I have a file download in the page it wont work since cache disabled.

Even history.back javascript function also not the correct solution.

What is a permanent solution for this problem? I have faced with this all the time and never found a consistent solution.

Can anyone suggest a possible solution for this?

Thanks
SNA

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to disable caching.  If you invalidate their session or authticket, you should be able to detect if they are signed out or not, in which case you can redirect them.  This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) may be helpful.    If you are really concerned with the back button try using clearing the clients history via javascript after you log them out.

EDIT
Check out [This Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201700/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111500-1.shtml) It goes in depth on some of the different approaches.  I don't think there is a sure fire way of keeping users from looking at previously downloaded content, but there are a few things you can do to make it difficult.

Comment: i was able to signout .but when i click back button in the browser it takes the cached page.Whichh is annoying eventhough links will not work.many clients dosent want this behaviour.can you plaese tell me the javscript function to clear history.